# In Spring MVC 4 i am getting Quartz Scheduler run Twice at a time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

In My Spring MVC project have, A Quartz Scheduler Which Will Run Twice at a time how to i fixed it and Get One Execution at a time.
where my web Initializer class is,

```
@WebListener
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    super.contextInitialized(sce);
    ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(TestJob.class).build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("simple").withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")).startNow().build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ctx.log("There was an error scheduling the job.", e);
    }
  }
}
```

And Test Class,

```
   public class TestJob implements Job {
@Override
public void execute(final JobExecutionContext ctx) throws 
 JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Executing Job");
  }
 }
```

and web Initializer Class like,

```
   public class WebAppInitializer extends 
      AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class[]{WebAppConfig.class, HibernateConfiguration.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
  }
```

and my WebConfig is,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.neron")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver resourceViewResolver(){
    ResourceBundleViewResolver viewResolver = new 
    ResourceBundleViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    viewResolver.setBasename("views");
    return viewResolver;
}
............
 ...............
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
public void schedulerCall()
{
    System.out.println("Calling");
}
```

> Here i get two times of "Executing Job" every minute, but i want only once 
>    "Executing Job" at every minute.
>   **can any one solve it ?  Thanks In Advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution 
add this annotation on the top of job class

```
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;// import this
   @DisallowConcurrentExecution
```

if you're working on cluster environment then different implementation. if you need comment here. or if your problem solved then accept it.

Comment: Thanks to reply dear, But not work. any other solutions .

Comment: No it just a Spring MVC project which is run on Tomcat Server. there are no any cluster environment.

Comment: can I share you with a simple example in spring 4.x

Comment: check you side i shared one more answer also added a link

Answer (score 0):

More information find GitHub link https://github.com/faizakram/Spring_Base_Exmaple_Annotation_Based

```
 //Configuration class
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableScheduling
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { CommonConstants.BASE_PACKAGE })
    public class WebMvcConfig {


            }

    //create a service method like this
     @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
            public void schedulerCall()
            {
                System.out.println("Calling");
            }
```

Comment: Hello Faiz when i trying it then get "Calling" four times per minute here i also update my WebAppConfig file in my Question. you can also see it ! Thanks

Comment: have you checked the github link and see flow

Comment: ya i already run this app (github) that is working fine . But Here i get twice in my Project.